# How Can We Get Date In Array From Dataset in C# Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how Would i get data in a new array from dataset i have four column in dataset but want to put only "power" and "date" column data in array ?

Hopes for your suggestions..

Regards,

Comment: can you please provide some relevant code so we can answer the question in a detailed manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a custom class which will represent your data:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could use a LINQ query on your DataSet to extract the necessary information:

```
DataSet dataSet = ...
Item[] result = dataSet
    .Tables[0]
    .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new Item
    {
        Power = row.Field<int>("power"),
        Date = row.Field<DateTime>("date"),
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: {DataSet output = new DataSet();
output.Tables.Add(dtGroupedBy);} i want this dataset data in array while my date format is {string dateformat = String.Format("{0:dddd MMM d}", date);} then your linq method would still work for it?

Comment: @Forums this will store the entire Date on the class -- you can choose how to format it when you need to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your .NET version and final usage you could use LINQ to DataSet to pull it out and project to a new type.

Something like this would work, if working on a Typed Dataset

```
var limitedData = from x in myDataSet
                  select new { Power = x.power, MyDate = x.date };
```

Then you have an IEnumerable that you can work with, you could use `.ToArray()` if you really need it in an array.

Comment: i am using 3.5 FW is there any alternate for it that would not use LINQ